Can't figure out how to configure Chakra-UI
I have this to templates main.jsx and app.jsx
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import { Provider } from "@chakra-ui/react";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

and app.jsx
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Button>Hello!</Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

I'm trying to configure and use Chakra-UI but that button won't be added there with everything that I tried
I also tried this in main.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import ChakraProvider from "@chakra-ui/react";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider>
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

The error for the first type of main.jsx is
The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@chakra-ui_react.js?v=88ddfe76' does not provide an export named 'Provider' (at main.jsx:4:10)

And for the second type
 The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@chakra-ui_react.js?v=88ddfe76' does not provide an export named 'default' (at main.jsx:4:8)

Please help me with some ideas...

Its import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";. The first example tries to import the named export Provider, which doesn't exist in @chakra-ui/react. The Second one is importing the default export (since its missing curly braces in the import statement) of the entire @chakra-ui/react package -- and it doesn't provide one anyway and isn't what you want.

The first error is caused by the wrong import statement in main.jsx file:
import { Provider } from "@chakra-ui/react";

Although I'm not sure which version you're using, for the latest version of Chakra the import statement should be:
// Corrected (1)
import { Provider } from "@/components/ui/provider"

With the above import statement the code should work.
For the second main.jsx file you've tried, the ChakraProvider should be inside curly braces like so:
// Corrected (2)
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';

However, this import statement is from V2.0 and I'm not sure how it would behave in the new 3.0 version. The documentation (here) for the new 3.0 version shows the import statement (1). For clarification on the uses of curly braces in import statements you can check this answer here.

The corrected 2 version I already tried, haven't tried the corrected 1 though, but unfortunatelly chatgpt made me delete that project:)) Anyway, thank you for you kind try to help

Well, in all honesty, I've been still using the old V2 version but decided to give V3 a shot and first one is the working one. Anyways, good luck with whatever you're working on!
